# Why the get request give empty response in Spring Boot?

Tags: spring-boot, rest, web-services, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to make simple rest services which can save the data to h2 database using JPA and show the data in response, but when I try POST request, the data that saved is null even though when I check the h2 console, the ID is entered saved because it use @GeneratedValue, but other is null. also when I want try GET request, the response give me null json

```
@Entity
public class MS_Product {
    
    @GeneratedValue
    @Id
    @Getter
    private long productId;
    
    @Getter @Setter
    private String productName;
    
    @Getter @Setter
    private int productPrice;
    
    @Getter @Setter
    private int productStock;
    
    @UpdateTimestamp
    @Getter
    private LocalDateTime updatedDate;
    
    
    
    protected MS_Product() {
        
    
    }

    public MS_Product(long productId, String productName, int productPrice, int productStock, LocalDateTime updatedDate) {
        super();
        this.productId = productId;
        this.productName = productName;
        this.productPrice = productPrice;
        this.productStock = productStock;
        this.updatedDate = updatedDate;
    }
    
    
    
    

}

    public interface MS_ProductRepository extends JpaRepository<MS_Product, Long>{
    
    }

    @RestController
    public class MS_ProductController {
        
    
        @Autowired
        MS_ProductRepository productRepository;
        
        @GetMapping("/products")
        public ResponseEntity<MS_Product> findAllProduct(){
            try {
                List<MS_Product> products = productRepository.findAll();
                
                return new ResponseEntity(products, HttpStatus.OK);
            }catch(Exception e){
                return new ResponseEntity<>(null, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
            }
        }
        
        @PostMapping("/products")
        public ResponseEntity<MS_Product> createProduct(@RequestBody MS_Product product){
            
            try {
                MS_Product savedProduct = productRepository.save(product);
                
                return new ResponseEntity(product, HttpStatus.CREATED);
            }catch(Exception e){
                return new ResponseEntity(null, HttpStatus.EXPECTATION_FAILED);
            }
        }
    }
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: MS_Product savedProduct = productRepository.save(product);                
return new ResponseEntity(product, HttpStatus.CREATED);
This returns what the user submitted, not the saved entity

Comment: In all probability an exception is being thrown. You catch exceptions but never log them. Start by logging the exception in the catch block. And then post the output because no one can help without that.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
@Entity(name="your_table_name")
public class Student {
```

Answer (score 0):

By design, the in-memory database is volatile and data will be lost when we restart the application.

We can change that behavior by using file-based storage. To do this we need to update the spring.datasource.url:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:file:/data/demo
```

Ref: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-h2-database

Answer (score 0):

You need

```
@Column(name = "productId")
```

on every your field which you need to map to table column

Comment: well, the annotation is optional, but it help to give a correct mapping between the field name and the column name, in my answer, the fieldname is the same as the column name, but not all the time they are the same.